# arduino sketch to subscribe to joint state msg

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use rosserial on arduino to subscribe to move_group/fake_controller_joint_states and then publish the first joints position on a topic chatter just to test verify that im receiving the position but it seems that the call back is not working as I don't seem to receive the values being sent on fake_controller_joint_states.  Im using an arduino mega, kinetic and ubuntu 16.04.  I greatly appreciate any direction or input.  thank you.

```
#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
#include <Arduino.h>
#else
#include <WProgram.h>
#endif
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;
std_msgs::Float64 mydata;

float angle[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

void cmd_cb(const sensor_msgs::JointState& cmd_arm)
{
  angle[0] = cmd_arm.position[0];
  angle[1] = cmd_arm.position[1];
  angle[2] = cmd_arm.position[2];
  angle[3] = cmd_arm.position[3];
  angle[4] = cmd_arm.position[4];
  angle[5] = cmd_arm.position[5];
}

ros::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::JointState> sub("/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states", cmd_cb);
ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &mydata);

void setup()
{
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
  nh.advertise(chatter);
}

void loop()
{
  mydata.data = angle[1];
  chatter.publish( &mydata );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

rostopic info /move_group/fake_controller_joint_states returns:

```
Type: sensor_msgs/JointState

Publishers: 
 * /move_group (http://chris-Latitude-3540:40629/)

Subscribers: 
 * /joint_state_publisher (http://chris-Latitude-3540:41687/)
 * /rostopic_5632_1530298559582 (http://chris-Latitude-3540:32869/)
 * /serial_node (http://chris-Latitude-3540:44431/)
```

rosnode info /serial_node returns:

```
Node [/serial_node]
Publications: 
 * /chatter [std_msgs/Float64]
 * /diagnostics [diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /move_group/fake_controller_joint_states [sensor_msgs/JointState]

Services: 
 * /serial_node/get_loggers
 * /serial_node/set_logger_level

contacting node http://chris-Latitude-3540:44431/ ...
Pid: 10725
Connections:
 * topic: /chatter
    * to: /rostopic_9634_1530306645550
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /move_group/fake_controller_joint_states
    * to: /move_group (http://chris-Latitude-3540:40629/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295816/arduino-sketch-to-subscribe-to-joint-state-msg/) by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-29**:
Have you run

```
rostopic info /move_group/fake_controller_joint_states
```

to check the topic's subscribers and publishers? You can also run

```
rosnode info <node-name>
```

to see what the node is subscribing to.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-29**:
What about

```
rosnode info /serial_node
```

?

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-06-29**:
added this to the question.  thank you

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-30**:
Not an answer, but: please note that `JointState` msgs are not meant to be used for commanding pose goals, but for reporting current joint states of your robot. Taking `fake_controller_joint_states` as input is also not very nice.

Look into `FollowJointTrajectory`.

**Comment by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) on 2018-06-30**:
i appreciate your feedback, what do you mean by "Taking fake_controller_joint_states as input is also not very nice"  Is this fopaux or against protocol? This seems to provides exactly what is needed for an open loop robot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-30**:
From the documentation:

> This is a message that holds data to describe the state of a set of [..] joints. [..] The header specifies the time at which the joint states were recorded.

Controlling joints is done with `FollowJointTrajectory` actions. Or at least, that is how it was designed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-30**:\

> Is this fopaux

I don't know what this means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to get it working by changing the baud rate to 115200

I added this line to the void_setup

```
nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);
```

I added the baud rate parameter to the rosserial launch:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=115200
```

This is the sketch that works:

```
#if (ARDUINO >= 100)
#include <Arduino.h>
#else
#include <WProgram.h>
#endif
#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/JointState.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;

float angle[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};

void cmd_cb(const sensor_msgs::JointState& cmd_arm)
{
  angle[0] = cmd_arm.position[0];
  angle[1] = cmd_arm.position[1];
  angle[2] = cmd_arm.position[2];
  angle[3] = cmd_arm.position[3];
  angle[4] = cmd_arm.position[4];
  angle[5] = cmd_arm.position[5];
 }

std_msgs::Float64 mydata;
ros::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::JointState> sub("/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states", cmd_cb);
ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &mydata);

void setup()
{
  nh.getHardware()->setBaud(115200);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.subscribe(sub);
  nh.advertise(chatter);
}

void loop()
{
  mydata.data = angle[1];
  chatter.publish( &mydata );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [chris annin](https://answers.ros.org/users/35464/chris-annin/) with karma: 58 on 2018-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1